# What are cells not affected by hormones called?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, terminology, endocrinology

Cells that are affected by hormones are called target cells which have their own receptors that listen to signals. I'm unsure of the actual name of cells that are not affected by hormones, I tried searching around on pages relating to target cells and the endocrine system, but no one seems to actually give a name to these cells that don't have receptors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about non-target cells? I found several examples of that usage including:

1. A book section titled:

   ### 9.3 How are steroid hormone target cells differentiated from non-target cells?<sup>1</sup>

   Containing the following line:

   > Thus, estrogen will stimulate mRNA and protein synthesis in a target cell, but not in a non-target cell.
2. A book chapter titled:

   ### Target or non-target: Hormonal signal perception and response in the determination of cell performance<sup>2</sup>

## References

1: [Brown, R., Brown, R. E., & Brown, R. E. (1994). An introduction to neuroendocrinology. Cambridge University Press., p. 149.](https://books.google.com/books?id=bXLd-BJd7CsC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA149&dq=hormone%20(%22non-target%20cell%22%20OR%20%22nontarget%20cell%22%20OR%20%22non%20target%20cell%22)&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q=hormone%20(%22non-target%20cell%22%20OR%20%22nontarget%20cell%22%20OR%20%22non%20target%20cell%22)&f=false)

2: [Osborne, D. J., & Thompson, D. S. (1992). Target or non-target: hormonal signal perception and response in the determination of cell performance. In Progress in Plant Growth Regulation (pp. 237-247). Springer, Dordrecht.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-011-2458-4_26)